# How to make HMVC In Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, hmvc

I have finished my previous project in yii2. Now, I'm currently working on laravel 5. I am new to laravel 5. I have googled about HMVC in laravel but I haven't found an appropriated answer (ie package) on Laravel. In Yii2 it provided by default .But I have not found in Laravel .Please suggest me How I work moduler way in Laravel 5.

Comment: https://github.com/caffeinated/modules

Comment: Please follow below link to get the correct answer. [How to make HMVC structure in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639577/how-to-make-hmvc-structure-in-laravel-5/47199218#47199218)

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this by using namespaces and grouping routes.
Look at my screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As You can see I've **2** top level **namespaces**: `Panel`, `Site`.
It's not problem to make controllers with namespace `SomeApp`, `SomeAnotherApp` and group their routes. using `Route::group`.

also read this discussion: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/multiple-modules-in-laravel-5?page=1

Comment: i have installed Laravel 5 but i am watching tutorials of Laravel 4 so can i run laravel 4's command in Laravel 5??

Comment: if You mean artisan commands to generate controllers and etc. - YES, it's same.

Comment: I get whatever I want